# Using SQLiteHelper. Retrieve Integer at position Row 2 Column 3, and assign a variable named "DansAge" to it, within an activity.

Tags: android, database, sqlite

```
           ## Sample Table ##
```

Here are some particulars concerning proposed problem.

```
    ROWID = _id;
    DataBase_Name = SimpleDatabase;
    DataBase_Table = StudentsAge;

         ID   Name   Age
         1    Bob     12
         2    Dan      9
```

Comment: If you ask on SO, please take the time to write a complete question including what you want to do, what you have tried and maybe some example data.

Comment: I have been working on the problem for some time. I didnt know there was a particular way to ask a quesion, or that there were police here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    cursor.moveToNext();
    int age = cursor.getInt(2);
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: This one works well, but if you have a lot of rows, you have to add additional "cursor.moveToNext();" statements to get to the row you want. If there is a faster way to get to row 10 without adding 10 "cursor.moveToNext();" statements, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this methode

```
    String getData = "SELECT Name , Age FROM " +TABLE_NAME ;
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(getData, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String Name = cursor.getString(0);
                int Age = cursor.getInt(1);
    }

    cursor.close();
```

Comment: Finally got this one to work, but it returns the last row only.

Comment: hii u can put cursor.moveToLast();

Comment: String name[] ;put out of While loop